# Merge an array by comparing the array of objects inside the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following array

```
    var array = [
        {
            group: "FL",
            list: [
                { key: "A", value: "Alaska" },
                { key: "B", value: "Brazil" },
                { key: "C", value: "California" }
            ]
        },
        {
            group: "NZ",
            list: [
                { key: "A", value: "Alaska" },
                { key: "B", value: "Brazil" },
                { key: "D", value: "Delhi" }
            ]
        },
        {
            group: "QA",
            list: [
                { key: "A", value: "Alaska" },
                { key: "B", value: "Brazil" },
                { key: "C", value: "California" }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I need to check the list array and if all the objects in the list array are exately same , then I need to merge it as below:

```
    [
        {
            group: "FL,QA",
            list: [
                { key: "A", value: "Alaska" },
                { key: "B", value: "Brazil" },
                { key: "C", value: "California" }
            ]
        },
        {
            group: "NZ",
            list: [
                { key: "A", value: "Alaska" },
                { key: "B", value: "Brazil" },
                { key: "D", value: "Delhi" }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I tried this by using reduce method to loop over the array and two other functions to compare the objects, but somehow its not working

```
    array.reduce(async(acc, item) => {
        const exist = await compareObjects(acc, item);
        if (exist) {
            acc[exist.index].group= exist.group + ',' + item.group;
        } else {
            acc.push(item)
        }
      return acc;
    }, [])
    async function compareObjects(o1, o2) {
        for (let i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
           const value = await checkObjs(o1[i].list, o2.list);
            if(value) { return {index:i  , group: o1[i].group} }
        }
    }

    function checkObjs(arr1, arr2) {
        return arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((el, i) => objectsEqual(el, arr2[i]))
    }

    const objectsEqual = (o1, o2) =>
        Object.keys(o1).length === Object.keys(o2).length
        && Object.keys(o1).every(p => o1[p] === o2[p]);
```

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Does the ordering in the list array matters?

Comment: You never return anything from `compareObjects`

Comment: @ikhvjs The order of the objects in list array doesnt matter.

Comment: You really don't need the awaits everywhere. All your ops are sync..

Comment: @pilchard Added the return statement in compareObjects function

Comment: You are returning a Promise from your callback, so the `acc` is a Promise not an array. Not sure your reason for the async

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `async` is what's tripping you up here, and I'm not sure your reason for using it.

To make your code work as is you need to `await` the accumulator on each iteration, and assign the result of the `reduce()` to something.

```js
var array = [ { group: 'FL', list: [ { key: 'A', value: 'Alaska' }, { key: 'B', value: 'Brazil' }, { key: 'C', value: 'California' }, ], }, { group: 'NZ', list: [ { key: 'A', value: 'Alaska' }, { key: 'B', value: 'Brazil' }, { key: 'D', value: 'Delhi' }, ], }, { group: 'QA', list: [ { key: 'A', value: 'Alaska' }, { key: 'B', value: 'Brazil' }, { key: 'C', value: 'California' }, ], }, ];

function checkObjs(arr1, arr2) {
  const objectsEqual = (o1, o2) =>
    Object.keys(o1).length === Object.keys(o2).length && Object.keys(o1).every((p) => o1[p] === o2[p]);

  return arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((el, i) => objectsEqual(el, arr2[i]));
}

async function compareObjects(o1, o2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
    const value = await checkObjs(o1[i].list, o2.list);
    if (value) {
      return { index: i, group: o1[i].group };
    }
  }
}

// assign the result of reduce to a variable
const result = array.reduce(async (acc, item) => {
  acc = await acc; // await the returned accumulator Promise

  const exist = await compareObjects(acc, item);

  if (exist) {
    acc[exist.index].group = exist.group + ',' + item.group;
  } else {
    acc.push(item);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

result.then((r) => console.log(r));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I don't support this answer, because it is not reusable. Everytime some async transformers are being used, one should remember to write `await accumolator`. It is better to have a `reduceAsync` utility, because it is reusable.

Comment: I agree it's a work around, but it points directly to why the OP's code wasn't working so seemed worth posting. I think your suggestion of a more reusable pattern is better in the long run, but only after knowing what is happening and whether async is even necessary to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to create a map of your input objects.

We'll create a function `getListKey()` to create a unique key based on each object list.

Once we have our map, we can use `Object.values()` to get the array result:

```js
var array = [ { group: "FL", list: [ { key: "A", value: "Alaska" }, { key: "B", value: "Brazil" }, { key: "C", value: "California" } ] }, { group: "NZ", list: [ { key: "A", value: "Alaska" }, { key: "B", value: "Brazil" }, { key: "D", value: "Delhi" } ] }, { group: "QA", list: [ { key: "A", value: "Alaska" }, { key: "B", value: "Brazil" }, { key: "C", value: "California" } ] } ]

function getListKey(list) {
    return JSON.stringify(list.sort(({ key: a }, { key: b }) => a.localeCompare(b)));
}

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, { group, list }) => { 
     const key = getListKey(list);
     if (!acc[key]) { 
         acc[key] = { group, list };
     } else {
         acc[key].group += "," + group;
     }
     return acc;
 }, {}))
 
 console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another way of approaching this is again using `Array.reduce()`, but using the lodash [_.isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) function for list comparison. This performs a deep comparison. We'd use this along with `Array.find()` to get any list duplicate.

```js
var array = [ { group: "FL", list: [ { key: "A", value: "Alaska" }, { key: "B", value: "Brazil" }, { key: "C", value: "California" } ] }, { group: "NZ", list: [ { key: "A", value: "Alaska" }, { key: "B", value: "Brazil" }, { key: "D", value: "Delhi" } ] }, { group: "QA", list: [ { key: "A", value: "Alaska" }, { key: "B", value: "Brazil" }, { key: "C", value: "California" } ] } ]

const result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
    const foundItem = acc.find(item => _.isEqual(item.list, cur.list));
    if (foundItem) {
        foundItem.group += `,${cur.group}`;
    } else {
        acc.push(cur);
    }
    return acc;
}, [])

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I've added a sort() to ensure key order is not relevant.

Comment: A suggestion: use `const key = JSON.stringify(
      list.sort(({ key: a }, { key: b }) => a.localeCompare(b))
    );` is good enough in the first example.

Comment: That's a good suggestion @ikhvjs!

Answer (score 0):

Reduce does not work with `async/await`. If you don't have `async` code - one that fetches something from an API or uses data from a Promise, you should remove the `async/await`, because it is synchronous.

If the code you have uses some async API - try using something like:

```js
export const reduceAsync = async (array, transformer, initialvalue) => {
    let accumolator = typeof initialValue !== 'undefined' ? initialValue : array[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        accumolator = await transformer(accumolator, array[i], i, array);
    }

    return accumolator;
};
```

The function above is reusable and follows the spec defined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @pilchard Well this is a workaround, but it makes the code harder to read in my opinion.

Comment: Removing Async/Await fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I would suggest going about this problem is by breaking it apart and (hopefully) using library functions to tackle some of the more complicated bits. For example with `lodash` you could say

```js
import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual";

const arr = [
  {
    group: "FL",
    list: [
      { key: "A", value: "Alaska" },
      { key: "B", value: "Brazil" },
      { key: "C", value: "California" }
    ]
  },
  {
    group: "NZ",
    list: [
      { key: "A", value: "Alaska" },
      { key: "B", value: "Brazil" },
      { key: "D", value: "Delhi" }
    ]
  },
  {
    group: "QA",
    list: [
      { key: "A", value: "Alaska" },
      { key: "B", value: "Brazil" },
      { key: "C", value: "California" }
    ]
  }
];

function groupBy<T, R>(
  a: T[],
  iteritem: (t: T) => R,
  compare: (a: R, b: R) => boolean = isEqual
) {
  const groups: T[][] = [];
  const rs = a.map(iteritem);
  for (let i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
    let added = false;
    const r = rs[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
      if (compare(r, iteritem(groups[j][0]))) {
        groups[j].push(a[i]);
        added = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!added) {
      groups.push([a[i]]);
    }
  }
  return groups;
}

const grouped = groupBy(arr, (a) => a.list);
const combined = [];
for (const g of grouped) {
  combined.push({
    group: g.map(({ group }) => group).join(","),
    list: g[0].list
  });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(combined, undefined, 2));
```

This isn't as much of a one off answer since `groupBy` could be reused. I originally wanted to use `groupBy` from `lodash` but it doesn't accept a custom equality function.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution:

```js
  const sorted = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    const identicalLists = [];

    for (let j = i; j < groups.length; j++) {
      const isIdentical =
        JSON.stringify(groups[i].list) === JSON.stringify(groups[j].list);
      const found = !!sorted.flat().find((item) => item === groups[j].group);
      if (isIdentical && !found) {
        identicalLists.push(groups[j].group);
      }
    }
    if (identicalLists.length > 0) {
      sorted.push(identicalLists);
    }
  }

  const answer = sorted.map((item) => {
    const first = groups.find((group) => group.group === item[0]);
    return { group: item, list: first.list };
  });
```